# Event loop in a command-line .NET app?

Tags: .net, vb.net, command-line-interface, event-loop

I have to adapt a GUI Visual Basic application to a command-line app. The GUI application waits for data arriving from a socket, and have a lot of async calls with `BeginInvoke`, like this one:

```
Private Sub m_frameParser_ConfigurationChanged() Handles m_frameParser.ConfigurationChanged

    BeginInvoke(New Action(AddressOf ConfigurationChanged))

End Sub
```

How can I adapt this to a command line application? Is there something like Node.js or Python3 event loop in VB.net?

Comment: Isn't it better to just remove (unwrap) those async calls to dispatcher? Of course you can make your own single-threaded message queue, but why?

Comment: Because the application waits for data that arrives from a TCP socket. I need that the console app will wait for the data indefinitely, and run a certain function when a certain event (ConfigurationChanged, ReceivedDataFrame, ConnectionTerminated, etc) is fired. Aka, an event loop.

Comment: Still don't see how is it related to BeginInvoke. This is usually called because UI applications are single-threaded and all manipulations with user interface should be marshalled to UI thread. But you don't have such problem in console application. Maybe you can provide a bit more detailed example of what BeginInvoke is used for now and how it is related to tcp?

Comment: `m_frameParser` is a GSF.PhasorProtocols.MultiProtocolFrameParser (see link below), an object that wraps a TCP (or UDP) connection and decode the arriving data using the specified protocol. `m_frameParser` emits `ConfigurationChanged` when the device that sends data changes its configuration, `ReceivedDataFrame` when a datum arrives, etc. http://www.gridprotectionalliance.org/NightlyBuilds/openPDC/Help/html/134b307f-d25f-3a28-d33d-6b37bfce3e6d.htm

Comment: I'm with Evk here; the only thing you need to change in the code above is to remove the BeginInvoke/AddressOf and just call your ConfigurationChanged method.  You shouldn't need an event loop (message pump or queue) for the events coming from m_frameParser; everything appears like it should 'just work' without BeginInvoke.  Your app waiting indefinitely on the socket should be unrelated to BeginInvoke - m_frameParser appears to be doing the indefinite waiting for you.

Comment: Yes, I missed the fact that all is managed by events. @Evk solution works, thank you.